# why elasticsearch not allowing to take snapshot without primary shards..?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, snapshot

My elasticsearch having only one cluster and one node.

```
In that i have one index that have only shards 2,4.
```

Because of that i am unable to take snapshot getting Primary shards not available.

**Is there any way to take snapshot with out primary shards..?**

and why my elasticsearch index having only 2,4 shards..? what happened to 0,1,3

Please help me

Comment: Post you cluster state/health info

Comment: **this is my cluster health**                                                                                      `{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 92,
  "active_shards" : 185,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 50
}`

Comment: Your cluster state is in red means some of the primary shards were not able to allocate. This means taking a snapshot is no meaningful. Did you completely shut down one of the nodes?

Comment: ya i did it .But there is no change what can i do

Comment: one more point i missed is , i have three machines in LAN with same cluster name of elasticsearch. In three machines per machine having one cluster named **elasticsearch** , one node named **0**,one index named **myindex** and shards **2 and 4**

Comment: If each machine is having same shard numbers, means you have set replica to 2? In your cluster health how come it is showing 92 active primary shards? Update replication to "0" temporarily and check the cluster health again